# Netty framework or how to use it with an AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask, netty

I'm trying to develop an Android application which is going to use [Netty](http://netty.io/).

First of all I want to test Netty on Android, so I'm going to develop [EchoClient](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/echo/package-summary.html) example.

I'm "translating" client part. This part has two classes: [EchoClient](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/echo/EchoClient.html) and [EchoClientHandler](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/echo/EchoClientHandler.html)

`EchoClient` is run as a thread, and `EchoClientHandler` handles all network stuff.

On main method, `EchoClient` is run like this:

`new EchoClient(host, port, firstMessageSize).run();`

`EchoClientHandler` uses an asynchronous event programming model.

Here is a piece of code of [EchoClient](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/echo/EchoClient.html):

```
public void run() {
    // Configure the client.
    ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(
            new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    // Set up the pipeline factory.
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(
                    new EchoClientHandler(firstMessageSize));
        }
    });

    // Start the connection attempt.
    ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

    // Wait until the connection is closed or the connection attempt fails.
    future.getChannel().getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();

    // Shut down thread pools to exit.
    bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
}
```

This `run()` method could be `AsyncTask.doBackground()` method.

As you can see [EchoClientHandler](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/echo/EchoClientHandler.html) is part of this class.

And this is [EchoClientHandler](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/echo/EchoClientHandler.html) method which I want to use in UI Thread:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(
        ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    // Send back the received message to the remote peer.
    transferredBytes.addAndGet(((ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage()).readableBytes());
    e.getChannel().write(e.getMessage());
}
```

How can I do to use EchoClientHandler in an AsynTask? I don't know how to update a TextView on `onProgressUpdate` when `messageReceived` is invoked.

Any advice?

Comment: did you ever get this to work? I'm trying to integrate Netty into an Android app and hitting a wall.

Comment: @Ash No, I didn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a callback.

**Step 1.** Define an interface

```
public interface MyCallback {
     public void onMessage(string msg);
}
```

**Step 2.** Take an object conforming to that interface in EchoHandler constructor and store it as a class variable

```
private MyCallback _myCallback
public EchoClientHandler(int firstMessageSize, MyCallback callback) {
   _myCallback = myCallback;
   ...
}
```

**Step 3.** Pass an object to that constructor in the pipeline. myCallback can come from run() as a parameter or in your EchoClient constructor.

```
// Set up the pipeline factory.
bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        return Channels.pipeline(
                new EchoClientHandler(firstMessageSize, myCallback));
    }
})
```

**Step 4.** Invoke call back in your message handler

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(
    ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    // Send back the received message to the remote peer.
    transferredBytes.addAndGet(((ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage()).readableBytes());
    e.getChannel().write(e.getMessage());

    _myCallback.onMessage("message");
}
```

Hope this helps.